# Nsight Eclipse fails to connect sshd on Jetson TX1

Tags: nvidia, remote-debugging

I could be able to remote my Tx1 via termial.
[image]

But I cannot be able to connect via nsight eclipse for remote debugging
[image]

I have found some information from this link: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/990118/nsight-eclipse-failed-to-connect-sshd-to-tx1-board/

But it still not solves my problem.
Is there any one has solved this, please give me some instruction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with my Nsight Eclipse.
After re-installing CUDA toolkit, the problem is solved.